# how to avoid wrap in DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div but when the text inside it is too long, it will wrap and make the div multiple lines.
This makes the page bad.
How can I avoid text in a div not wrap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502500/css-word-wrapping-in-div

Comment: Just add the following style: `<div style="white-space: nowrap;">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason the test is wrapping. But if you don't care for then then you set the overflow style to visible and set the `style="white-space: nowrap;"` style as well

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the desired result. If you MUST keep the div fixed size, sacrificing some of the visible text that doesn't fit, use `width`, `height` and `overflow: hidden`, otherwise you use `white-space: nowrap` as already suggested.