# CSS 2.1: Wrap Text Inside Div

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Ydjde/

The problem is the text inside div is not confined to the div. It breaks the div and write. How can we wrap the text inside the div itself with following features?

•   The full text will be readable

•   It will not break the div

Is there a way to use it in **CSS 2.1**? I believe word-wrap is CSS 3.0 feature.

Note: I have **width** defined as width:100px; and width:30px; for the first and second divs

Note: The span is generated from ASP.Net Label control. Hence we cannot change/replace the **span**. The problem is to be resolved using CSS.

```
 <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_Label1">25123456789</span>
```

[image]

Reference:

1. [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)
2. [CSS word-wrapping in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502500/css-word-wrapping-in-div)
3. [CSS3 word-wrap Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS word-wrapping in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502500/css-word-wrapping-in-div)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question in for doing it using CSS 2.1

Comment: How early of a browser do you need to support? Word-wrap is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`word-wrap: break-word;` is your friend. See your [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ydjde/1/).

Comment: @Lijo: Technically this is not CSS2.1; it's completely non-standard. But given the question, I suppose "CSS2.1" here really means "supported by IE6+"

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks. I meant IE6+ only. Do you have any suggestion that satisfy CSS2.1 and IE6+ ?

Comment: @Lijo: Nope. IE6 isn't CSS2.1-compliant so you'll be hard pressed to find many of its features that will work.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean `word-wrap: break-word`?

http://jsfiddle.net/PhRKh/

(edit: oops, didn't see the other answer)

Comment: Is there a way for CSS 2.1? I am getting a warning in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

```
you add change width:35px  then work properly

   .fixedColumnValue{
      width:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found something strange here about `word-wrap` only works with `width` property of css properly.

here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hss5g/) that i have prepared about it.

I know its too late but it could help others!