# text not expanding the div

Tags: html, css, clearfix

In my *card*, the text is not expanding vertically the div. I tried to use the `clear` property, but doesn't helped. Any ideas?

here is my actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/kuupsdm5/1

[image: Card]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `.card-body` class:

```
.card-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You have a very long word there and if you don't include the `word-wrap:break-word;` it will stay on a single line.  Width 100% along with the padding was also causing the line to extend beyond the others, so either remove the padding or width 100% from the class.

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kuupsdm5/2/)

Comment: Hey if we keep `width:auto;` , is there any problem?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problems, but it's not necessary to include.

Answer (score 3):

It because you have `.card-body` as a single word just add this property `word-wrap: break-word;` and remove `width:100%`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kuupsdm5/5/)**

Comment: Width 100% is also causing mis-alignment FYI

Comment: Agree that its because he is having some padding for his text.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ... into the Body Style

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

May be Duplicate of

[CSS 2.1: Wrap Text Inside Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388088/css-2-1-wrap-text-inside-div)

**UPDATE**

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kuupsdm5/12/)

Comment: Width 100% is also causing mis-alignment FYI

Comment: That did the trick, but I tried before without eht width: 100%