# Wrapping text to new line inside div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs where the text inside them will often change.  When the contents inside the two divs becomes two wide for the container div I would like the left div to wrap the text to a new line.

This is my desired results:
[image: This is my desired result:]

```
<html>
    <head>
         <style type="text/css">
             #header {
                position:relative;
                height: 100px;
                width:150PX;
              }

              #leftdiv {
                position: absolute;
                float:left;
                left:0px;
                bottom:0px;
                font-size: 10px; 
               }     

              #rightdiv {
                position:absolute;
                float:right;
                right:0px;
                bottom:0px;
                font-size: 10px; 
             }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div id="header">
             <div id="leftdiv">Content in Left Div</div>
             <div id="rightdiv">Content in Right More</div>
          </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502500/css-word-wrapping-in-div?

Comment: Is there a particular reason the elements need to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: You dont seem to have any `width` set for those `div`s... That should be your problem.

Comment: I don't want to set a width because the width of the text will change

Comment: Yes the absolute positions places the divs where I want them in the container

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5yTgV/ ?

Comment: Using position absolute you can't solve it. You will have to find another way to layout your elements. Probably `display: inline-block` or `table_cell` ? And put a width on the right element to make sure the left one breaks.

Comment: @Colandus how will putting a width on the right one break the left element? That makes less sense than his initial approach without widths..

Comment: Ok, thanks guys.  It looks like I need to find another approach.

Comment: If you elaborate more on what exactly you want to do, we could help... What you explained made little to no sense :)

Comment: I agree with @GiovanniSilveira pls. elaborate more on what exactly what you want so we can help you to solve your problem, using `float` having `width` also solve your problem. [http://jsfiddle.net/5yTgV/

Answer (score 5):

Use this `word-wrap: break-word;`

Assign all those divs in which you want text to wrap a class and then style that class using `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Thats not the problem