# What does "anywhere" mean in "word-wrap" css property?

Tags: css, word-wrap

I just noticed in Firefox (I assume it's the same in Chrome) a new property value called "anywhere" of a property "word-wrap". What does it do? I remember using normal (which is default) or break-word (for most uses) but what does "anywhere" mean? How is it different from "break-word"? Mozilla.org doesn't have it listed in their manual (yet?)

"anywhere" seems to do the same thing "break-word" does. I'm seeing this in Firefox 67.0

```css
word-wrap: anywhere;
```

I don't really know what to make of it. Is it usefull? Has it always been there all this time and I just missed it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-overflow-wrap) to find the definition:

> anywhere
>
> An otherwise unbreakable sequence of characters may be broken at an arbitrary point if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line. Shaping characters are still shaped as if the word were not broken, and grapheme clusters must stay together as one unit. No hyphenation character is inserted at the break point. Soft wrap opportunities introduced by anywhere are considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.

and later you can read:

> break-word
>
> **As for anywhere** except that soft wrap opportunities introduced by break-word are not considered when calculating min-content intrinsic sizes.

---

Simply notice that the browser support is quite limited:

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#Browser_compatibility

Comment: So that's where CSS is being developed. I recon this IS a new thing as I thought, right? Anyways that does answer my question, thank you.

Comment: @GlennCarver this is the offical specification, so yes it's where things are decided before implemented.